# generate video containing scrolling image

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to generate a video [let's say 800x600] from a 800x10000 still image.

The image has to scroll, from top to bottom as if someone was actually scrolling a page.

If it could scroll faster over some portions and slower over others, that would be great, if not I think I could just make a few separate videos and then just stitch them up.

I cannot find any documentation on this subject; could anyone give me a hint? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [scroll](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scroll) filter. The [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter is optional and will output a reasonable width and height for large image inputs. You can consider using the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter too. The [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) filter outputs a widely compatible pixel format / chroma subsampling scheme.

## Vertical

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -vf "scroll=vertical=0.01,crop=iw:600:0:0,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

## Horizontal

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.png -vf "scroll=horizontal=0.01,crop=800:600:0:0,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

#### Scroll filter options

- `horizontal, h` Set the horizontal scrolling speed. Default is 0. Allowed range is from -1 to 1. Negative values changes scrolling direction.
- `vertical, v` Set the vertical scrolling speed. Default is 0. Allowed range is from -1 to 1. Negative values changes scrolling direction.
- `hpos` Set the initial horizontal scrolling position. Default is 0. Allowed range is from 0 to 1.
- `vpos` Set the initial vertical scrolling position. Default is 0. Allowed range is from 0 to 1.

Comment: could you also point out how to add an audio source? I tried variations on this, but none worked `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=851x600:d=20 -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=851:8680[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.05':shortest=1[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:0 /3.mp4`

Comment: @SorinButurugeanu Updated example to include audio. If it doesn't work you can supply your command and the complete console output.

Comment: another small question: how do I get the current clip duration? I have to type it manually again in the formula in the filter_complex - 60. Is there no variable for the clip length, like there is for width and height? [main_w / main_h]?
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=750x360:d=60:r=30 -loop 1 -i /4339550983562.jpg -i /2.mp3 -i /copy.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=750:-1[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y='min(-h+main_h+(h-main_h)*t/60, 0)':shortest=1[gg]; [gg][3:v]overlay=10:main_h-h-10[gh]" -shortest -map "[gh]" -map 2:a /xx.mp4`

Comment: Why ```scroll=horizontal=-0.01``` changes the direction, but ```scroll=horizontal=-1``` doesn't ?

Comment: @ArmKh I'm not sure. You'll have to look at `libavfilter/vf_scroll.c`. May have to use `-0.99` or so.

Comment: On `ffmpeg version N-92517-gd0f5942` I get `[AVFilterGraph @ 0x3db4b00] No such filter: 'scroll'`. Any idea why?

Comment: @PedroLobito That version is not in the git log. It's from a fork. You'll need to get the real ffmpeg.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest version for windows and the scroll filter works as intended, thank you.