# FFmpeg, animation types: How to move the video screen along the large images?

Tags: animation, video, ffmpeg, slideshow, video-processing

My output video sizes are **1280x720**. And I have an images with these sizes

1. *3000x1200*
2. *1200x2000*

So, I need to animate the large images inside the small video frames. The first image should be animated **from right to left** and the second one **from top to bottom**. In other words it will be something like moving screen along the pictures

In [this](https://slideshow.myvedit.com/assets/video/slideshow-sample.mp4) video example you can see the animations like that. 
So, how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use an animated crop.</strike>

Use the scroll filter. I completely forgot about this. See duplicate link above.

Comment: Thank you @llogan .
For the verical animation I've tried this ```ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 4 -i input.jpg -filter_complex "crop=720:1280:(oh/4)*t" vertical.mp4``` command, but the video doesn't play after that

Comment: Also, is there any wat to slow down the crop animation?

Comment: I've done it using this ```crop=1280:720:ow:(oh/4)*t```. Thank you!

Comment: So, I have **from top to bottom** and **from left to right** animations. But what if I want to change the directions? **From bottom to top** and **from right to left**. I've tried ```-ow``` and ```-oh```, but it didn't work

Comment: @ArmKh See [this forgotten answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318357/1109017) for an easier method.