# generate video containing scrolling image using MLT

Tags: mlt

I want to generate a video [let's say 1920x1020] from a 1920x10000 still image.

The image has to scroll, from top to bottom as if someone was actually scrolling a page.

Found answers how to make it with ffmpeg, but i need to scroll it in mlt as i have a lot of other tasks there.

```
melt -profile atsc_1080p_2997 1.jpg length=300 -filter affine transition.geometry="0=0,0:100%x100%;300=0,-500:100%x100%"
```

This scrolls, but image is centered and i need to calculate pixels...
Is there any way to make it like with ffmpeg? ([generate video containing scrolling image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316446/generate-video-containing-scrolling-image)) (just pass needed length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLT does not have a similar scroll filter. The method you used is the recommended/preferred way to scroll in MLT.

> ...i need to calculate pixels

You can use percent instead of pixels if that helps.

Comment: The main problem is that picture is centered and when i increase it's size so it's width became same as video it moves right and now i need somehow to calculate in pixels to move it left...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter and filter service's name is [affine](https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterAffine/).