# how to use ffmpeg for top and bottom image panning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

here is the code for left to right pan:

```py
import os

cmd = "ffmpeg -nostdin -loop 1 -i " + url1 + " -filter_complex " +  " [0:v]crop=ih:ih:iw-ih-iw*t/8+ih*t/8:0,trim=duration=5,scale=-2:720 " + " -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p " + url2

os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: See [generate video containing scrolling image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316446/generate-video-containing-scrolling-image/24318357#24318357)

Comment: http://ffmpeg.unixpin.com/2018/09/27/image-animation-pan/